# How to create submodule in python? Thank

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to create submodule in python? Thanks! 
I need write `_init__.py`?
It name will be `pybase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A folder with .py files and a **init**.py is called a package. One of those files containing classes and functions is a module. Folder nesting can give you subpackages.

So for example if I had the following structure:

```
mypackage
__init__.py
module_a.py
module_b.py
mysubpackage
__init__.py
module_c.py
module_d.py
```

I could import mypackage.module_a or mypackage.mysubpacakge.module_c and so on.

You could also add functions to mypackage (like the numpy functions you mentioned) by placing that code in the **init**.py. Though this is usually considered to be ugly.

If you look at numpy's **init**.py you will see a lot of code in there - a lot of this is defining these top-level classes and functions. The **init**.py code is the first thing executed when the package is loaded.